# Diagnosing problem with running ASP.NET app as 64-bit

Tags: .net, asp.net, 64-bit

I need to run an ASP.NET app as 64-bit.  The app is quite large and has MANY assemblies to load.  When I run it I am getting "is not a valid Win32 application" error in the web page as soon as I go to the first page.  That page is a very simple "Hello World" page.  However, it must be having problem with loading assemblies as 64-bit.  How can I figure out which one(s) are the problem?

Comment: I have 64-bit OS and need to run the app using 64-bit

Answer (score 2):

When you say "run as 64-bit" do you mean you are running on Windows 2008 x64/IIS 7? Also if you are having trouble running an app that worked fine on the 32-bit flavor, you can use [CorFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699%28VS.80%29.aspx) to specifically tell your assemblies to run in 32 bit mode on a x64 machine. This came very handy on our new Citrix farm which was all Win2k8 64-bit, we had a lot of vendor .net apps behave strangely/not work at all, until we discovered this tool

Comment: I need to run 64-bit.  The test machine I am using is Win XP Pro 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

are you running IIS in 64 bit mode?  http://blog.danbartels.com/archive/2005/05/18/662.aspx

Comment: yes, I am running IIS in 64-bit mode.  I want the app to run in 64-bit.